# Undo an hg push (backout?)

Tags: mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

I made a big oops, and could use some help undoing it.

We have two repositories-a fairly stable repository, and a repository we're working on changes in.  I just made a defect fix in our stable repository, and was moving it up to the working repository.  I pulled from the stable repository, merged, then accidentally pushed to the stable repository.

The stable repository now looks like this:

```
*merge
| \
|  \
|   *b
*a  |
|  / 
*c
```

where `a` is the commit that should be the tip of the stable repository, `b` is all the stuff that we've done in the development repository, and `c` is the point we branched the development repository.

How do I go about making it back to:

```
*a
|
*c
```

(I know I can't really make changes go away, I'm just looking for a functional structure...)

I've read some things that make me think that `hg backout` is the command I need, but I'm not exactly sure what it does.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`hg rollback` reverts the last transaction, so you'd be left with unfinished merge, which you have to use `hg update -C` to get out.

If you don't want *b (you have it in another clone), then enable the built-in MQ extension and run `hg strip -r <*b>`. It will get rid of *b and *merge. By default it saves a backup in case you change your mind again.

---

UPDATE (per @Rudi's comment: sorry I missed the "already pushed" part)

Since the merge is already pushed out, **NEVER EVER** do what I suggested earlier. Hate emails from fellow developers would have been the best outcome.

Do this instead:

```
hg up -r<*merge>
hg revert -r<*a> -a
hg ci -m "undo unintended merge"
```

Or you could be more kosher:

```
hg up -r<*merge>
hg backout -r<*merge> --parent<*a>
```

Comment: Since the merge is already pushed, the merge-commit cant be rolled back (push and pull are also transactions). Also this operation wold be needed to be done in every working copy which pulled this commit from the stable repository.

Comment: What's the difference between using backout and revert?  I ended up using backout, but I'd like to know my options (even though I hope it never happens again!)

Comment: `backout` commits a new changeset on top of your existing changesets to effectively reverse the changes. `revert` changes your working copy and does not commit.

Comment: FYI `hg backout --parent` is now deprecated (the `--parent` part)

Answer (score 2):

I think it to late to make `hg rollback` since you have already pushed your changes.

You might try with MQ extensions but this also works locally. `hg strip` will only modify your local repo. You could of course try to modify your server repo directly on server but if somebody pulled it it is too late.

Another option is described in [chapter 9](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html) of **hgbook** in section *Backing out a merge*. It involves `hg backout` command but it might be an overkill for you...

I suggest to `hg update -C` to *a revision, merge with tip and ignore all changes from *merge? Your repository will look more or less like this than:

```
*second merge
 |  \ 
 |   \ 
 |    \     
 |     \ 
*merge | 
| \    |
|  \   |
|   *b |
*a  | /
|  / /
*c---
```

Commands for this are

- `$ hg --config ui.merge=internal:local merge  #keep my files`
- `$ hg --config ui.merge=internal:other merge  #keep their files`

More details could be found [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge).

Answer (score 0):

`hg rollback` will revert the one last commit, deleting any history that would otherwise been made.

So, if you start with this:

```
*merge
| \
|  \
|   *b
*a  |
|  / 
*c
```

hg rollback will give:

```
*a  *b
|  / 
*c
```

note that you can only do `hg rollback` only once.

You should make a complete backup of the repository before doing rollback. To do this, simply `hg clone` the whole repository.

Comment: I think you mean rollback, not backout. :)

Answer (score 0):

You all present little to complicated solution to this problem, that can occur to any of us.

What I did, I logged on remote desktop to my central repository, and there with `mq` extension changed revision status to "draft" and "stip"-ed them.

The only downside of it is, if someone has copy of repo with stripped revisions and will push, they will reappear. So if you can, ask others to
a) do the same (draft, strip)
b) delete their local repository and resync with modified one

All can be achieved easily with [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/).